# Can $f: \mathbb{R} \to [0, +\infty)$, where $f(x) = 2^x$ be a function?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

I am really confused about this. Here is what I understand :
The domain is $\mathbb{R}$ (so $[-∞,+∞]$)  and the codomain $[0, +∞)$.
In order for it to be a function, all values of the domain need to be related to a unique value in the codomain. But my concern is that, since the codomain is $[0,+∞)$, it means that $∞$ is not included in the codomain. Does that mean $\infty$ in the domain is not related to a value?

Comment: $\mathbb R = (-\infty, +\infty). [-\infty,+\infty] = \overline{\mathbb R}$

Comment: The domain is $\mathbb{R}=(-∞,+∞)$. $\pm\infty$  are not real numbers.The codomain of $2^x$ is $(0,+\infty)$. There is also the so-called EXTENDED real line which is denoted by $\overline{{R}}=[∞,+∞]. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_real_number_line

Comment: More explicitly, there is **no finite** real number $x$ such that $2^x = 0.$  Therefore, the answer to the question is **no**.

Comment: No offense, but literally everything you wrote for what you understand is wrong lol.